How to Modify Symfony Entity Getter Method to Return Date-only Values in REST API Responses?
I'm currently developing a Symfony-based REST API application, where I encounter a specific requirement related to the formatting of date values returned from entity fields. Within my entity, I have a field named birthdate, defined as @ORM\Column(type="date"). When this field is included in API responses, it provides both the date and time components, which is not aligned with the project's specifications. Instead, I need the API response to exclusively provide the date part without any time information.
Below is a condensed version of the relevant section of the entity, including the existing getBirthdate() method:
/**
 * @var \DateTime|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthdate", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $birthdate;

// Existing getBirthdate() method
public function getBirthdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->birthdate;
}

// Additional properties and methods...

While I've considered utilizing DateTimeImmutable objects to ensure immutability, I'm uncertain about the precise implementation within the getBirthdate() method. Therefore, I seek guidance on how to modify this method effectively to exclusively return the date part without any time components, utilizing DateTimeImmutable.

As shown here, you can use a Context attribute to set a specific date format for your field:
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Context;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer;

#[Context([DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'Y-m-d'])]
private $birthdate;

